# How to manage pause/resume recurring payments with firstdata payment gateway

Tags: php, credit-card, firstdata

We have implemented credit card payment processing with firstdata on PHP website, where user enters credit card details in site itself and does payment. For that we have implemented firstdata payment gateway - https://www.payeezy.com using CURL API

Is their any way that using API we can pause or resume the subscriptions from our website. That is user logs into his account and select his subscription and do pause or resume ?

Thanks.